# sorting with uasort (multiple conditions)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, usort

I'd like to use uasort to sort a multidimensional array. The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612134001
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 'a'
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612134000
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 'b'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612171201
            [1] => 0
            [] => 'c'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612171200
            [1] => 0
            [] => 'd'
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612220400
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 'e'
        )
)
```

I expected output should look like this (sort timestamp asc [0] but if [1] is 0 put it above, but still consider the timestamp):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612171200
            [1] => 0
            [] => 'd'
        )
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612171201
            [1] => 0
            [] => 'c'
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612134000
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 'b'
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612134001
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 'a'
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1612220400
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 'e'
        )
)
```

I tried uasort but they overwrite each other. Is it possible to do it in one uasort? I couldn't find anything about it.

```
  uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a[0] - $b[0];
  });
  
  uasort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a[1] - $b[1];
  });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: Search for a section titled "Sorting by multiple fields" in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @El_Vanja thank you for the link. I've already taken a look at it but I couldn't figure it out :(

Comment: Have you tried writing anything like it? If so, can you share the effort and explain how it fails? The code you show in the question performs two separate sorts.

Comment: @El_Vanja I tried (order isn't correct, timestamps are not as). I would really appreciate it, if you can give me the if statement for my issue. if (($a[1] - $b[0]) > 0) {
      return $a[0] - $b[0];
    }
    return $a[1] - $b[1];

Comment: That condition is wrong (for one, it doesn't even compare the same data, you take `[1]` from `$a`, but take `[0]` from `$b`). Change it to `if ($a[1] === $b[1])` and it should be fine.

Comment: @El_Vanja works like a charm. thank you!! and sorry for my late reply.

Answer (score 2):

It should be sorted in ascending order according to index 1 and then in ascending order according to index 0 (timestamp). The '[spaceship](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator)' operator <=> and the 'Elvis' operator ?: are very useful for a smart solution.

```
$in = [
    [1612134001, 1, 'a'],
    [1612134000, 1, 'b'],
    [1612171201, 0, 'c'],
    [1612171200, 0, 'd'],
    [1612220400, 1, 'e'],
];

//sort
usort($in, function ($a, $b) {
  return $a[1] <=> $b[1]  //first 
      ?: $a[0] <=> $b[0]  //second
  ;}
);

//Test
$expected = [
  [1612171200, 0, 'd'],
  [1612171201, 0, 'c'],
  [1612134000, 1, 'b'],
  [1612134001, 1, 'a'],   
  [1612220400, 1, 'e'],
];

var_dump($in === $expected);  //bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a little testing this seems to work

```
$in = [
    [1612134001, 1, 'd'],
    [1612134000, 1, 'c'],
    [1612171201, 0, 'b'],
    [1612171200, 0, 'a'],
    [1612220400, 1, 'e'],
    [1612133999, 1, '??'],
];


uasort($in, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a[1] == $b[1] && $a[0] == $b[0]) {
        return 0; 
    }
    if ($a[1] < $b[1]){
        return -1;
    }else if ($a[0] < $b[0] && $a[1] == $b[1]) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

});
```