# sort array of arrays in php by parameter with all the fields

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hey All I have this object in php. that I want to sort by timestamp the array in variable $tempData

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;06:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '06',
 
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;08:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '08',
  
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;03:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '03',

  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;00:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '00',

  ),
)
```

I try this code from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597736/how-to-sort-an-array-of-associative-arrays-by-value-of-a-given-key-in-php](https://answer)

```
$sortedArray = array();
            foreach ($tempData as $key => $row)
            {
            $sortedArray[$key] = $row['Timestamp'];
            }
            array_multisort($sortedArray, SORT_DESC, $tempData);
```

And the result is

```
[2022-02-21 05:26:30] local.INFO: The sorted data are:   
[2022-02-21 05:26:30] local.INFO: array (
  0 => '2022-02-21&nbsp;06:00',
  1 => '2022-02-21&nbsp;08:00',
  2 => '2022-02-21&nbsp;03:00',
  3 => '2022-02-21&nbsp;00:00',
```

However I need all the origin array to be displayed, all the objects . meaning it will be the same object as $tempData with all the nodes, but sorted and not just to sort the field.
can someone advise?

I tried also this code:

```
function asc_sort_json($array1,$array2){
            $on = 'Timestamp';
            if ($array1[$on] == $array2[$on]) {
                return 0;
            }
            return ($array1[$on] < $array2[$on]) ? -1 : 1;
        }

        usort($tempData, "asc_sort_json");
```

and get this error:

```
local.ERROR: usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'asc_sort_json' not found or invalid function name {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'asc_sort_json' not found or invalid function name at
```

Comment: You should be using `usort` or `uasort` for this. As you could have already deduced from the duplicate your first question about this (https://stackoverflow.com/q/71198066/1427878) was closed with, and as you have been told again when you asked about this the second time, https://stackoverflow.com/q/71202926/1427878

Comment: tried the usort getting error, see the edits

Comment: That's not reproducible with the snippet you have shown. https://3v4l.org/XLn2n clearly shows that it works that way, in principle.

Comment: OK but this is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
$tempData = [
  [
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;06:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '06',
 
  ],
  [
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;08:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '08',
  
  ],
  [
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;03:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '03',

  ],
  [
    'Timestamp' => '2022-02-21&nbsp;00:00',
    'Date' => '2022-02-21',
    'Hour' => '00',
  ],
];

$Timestamp = array_column($tempData, 'Timestamp');

array_multisort($Timestamp, SORT_DESC, $tempData);

print_r($tempData);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Timestamp] => 2022-02-21 08:00
            [Date] => 2022-02-21
            [Hour] => 08
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Timestamp] => 2022-02-21 06:00
            [Date] => 2022-02-21
            [Hour] => 06
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Timestamp] => 2022-02-21 03:00
            [Date] => 2022-02-21
            [Hour] => 03
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Timestamp] => 2022-02-21 00:00
            [Date] => 2022-02-21
            [Hour] => 00
        )

)
```